# Can't import existing android projects into eclipse..

Tags: android, eclipse, adt

I had deleted org.eclipse.core.resources cause I had trouble starting eclipse. and after I deleted it eclipse finally starts but when I try to import my existing projects from my workspace into eclipse, it won't display anything on project explorer and it does not display any errors at all.. Does anybody had experience this before? Im on 64bit UBUNTU13.04. By the way I have the Android IDE Build: v22.0.5-757759..

Comment: That sounds like a pretty important thing to delete. Are you sure that was the right thing to do?

Comment: I would strongly recommend removing your eclipse and android sdk and re-installing it all fresh.

Comment: I read a post here that involves deleting org.eclipse.core.resources.. to make my eclipse run again.. cause before I deleted it, eclipse would display an error..

Comment: /home/dreamer/workspace/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.core.resources - this is the file that I deleted.. Do I really need to reinstall everything?

Comment: Yes you will have to reinstall it sorry, annoying ae!

Comment: @Nicholas I switch to another workspace and import existing android project to my project explorer and it appears.. However I have 3 projects on my old workspace, only 2 are visible on my project explorer.. by the way I have not reinstalled yet.. what is the problem with this? why I can't see my 3rd project? even I import it again and again

Comment: I see the problem, when I open the files on my 3rd project, the androidmanifest.xml is blank, the java files are blank, I don't know why are those blank.. Those files are impt. for me cause it is one of my unfinished projects.. does anybody know the reason for it? how to recover it or fix it?